# opencv .at handle different image types

Tags: c++, opencv

I have some code that I want to be able to handle both 8-bit and 16-bit images.

the only difference between the code right now is that the 8-bit code uses:

```
filename.at<uchar>(i, j)
```

and the  16-bit code uses:

```
filename.at<ushort>(i, j)
```

Now the easiest way is to just include an if statement at the top that checks the image type and then I just have two blocks of code that do the same thing, but I would like to aoid this since maintenance becomes kind of a pain.

First, I read through the OpenCV documentation and I may have missed it, but I did not see anything that returns the data type the Mat object uses to store pixel data. So if I missed it I will feel silly, but that would be best.

The other option I looked into was a function pointer, but I am unsure if I can do this for the .at template function.

Any advice on any of these options is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to simply branch based on the depth of the input. (Thanks for the inspiration, perfanoff!)

Before you access individual pixels:

```
bool eightBit = false;  //I assume 8- and 16-bits are the only options
if (m.depth() == CV_8U)
    eightBit = true;
```

Doing the comparison before any pixel access is an optimization so you avoid calling `.depth()` and doing the comparison for each pixel, since the result never changes.

Then, in your loop:

```
if (eightBit)
{
 // Something using m.at<uchar>(i,j) 
}
else
{
 // Something using m.at<ushort>(i,j)
}
```

This will allow both read and write access to the pixel data. However, branching in your inner loop like this might be bad for performance.

Comment: this option falls under the first solution I outlined and so far it is working, I am just looking for a way to avoid this since the code I need to determine type on is 50 lines long and with many m.at<>() statements through the entire code. so I would have to duplicate this code block for each possible image type I want to read. and I am hoping there is a way that allows me less code reuse and easier maintenance so if some thing needs to change in this code later I do not have to go through each block and edit them all.

Comment: Perhaps you could post said code (or a small sampling thereof) to help us get a better idea of what's going on. Since you stated you can't use a template, I can't think of a solution that doesn't involve either a branch (like mine), or defining two different functions somewhere (like the function pointer approach).

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own function to access an element in the Mat. You should test how much slower it would be, though.

```
inline ushort GetPixel(const Mat& m,int x,int y)
{
    if (m.depth == CV_8U)
       return m.at<uchar>(x,y);
    else return m.at<ushort>(x,y);
}
```

Comment: I thought about this, but I need to be able to write in as well as read out since I do edit the values of some pixels in my code and this kind of inline function will not allow me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

here's my 2 ct. :

```
template < class T > 
void myfunction( Mat & img ) {
    // code with a lot of img.at<T>(y,x);
}
```

and call it:

```
myfunction<ushort>(img);
```

or :

```
myfunction<uchar>(img);
```

Comment: I appreciate the idea, but there are some external requirements on my code that I did not want to muddle the issue with. However, these requirements mean I need to be able to do it in the middle of a function.